# Regex Matching Conflict with Overlapping Symbol

Tags: java, regex, token

I'm trying to match tokens that all the contain the symbol `<` or `>`, but there are some conflicts. In particular, my tokens are `<`, `>`, `</`, `/>`, and a comment that starts with `<!--` and ends with `-->`.

My regexes for these are as follows:

```
String LTHAN = "<"; 
String GTHAN = ">";
String LTHAN_SLASH = "</";
String GTHAN_SLASH = "/>";
String COMMENT = "<!--.*-->";
```

And I compile them by adding them to a list using the general method:

```
public void add(String regex, int token) {
    tokenInfos.add(new TokenInfo(Pattern.compile("^(" + regex + ")"), token));
}
```

Here is what my TokenInfo class looks like:

```
private class TokenInfo {
    public final Pattern regex;
    public final int token;

    public TokenInfo(Pattern regex, int token) {
        super();
        this.regex = regex;
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

I match and display the list as follows:

```
public void tokenize(String str) {
    String s = new String(str);
    tokens.clear();
    while (!s.equals("")) {
        boolean match = false;

        for (TokenInfo info : tokenInfos) {
            Matcher m = info.regex.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
                match = true;

                String tok = m.group().trim();
                    tokens.add(new Token(info.token, tok));

                s = m.replaceFirst("");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read and display:

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br;
        String curLine;
        String EOF = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {    
            File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\input files\\example.xml");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir));

            while ((curLine = br.readLine()) != EOF) {
                sb.append(curLine);
                // System.out.println(curLine);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        tokenizer.tokenize(sb.toString());

        for (Tokenizer.Token tok : tokenizer.getTokens()) {
            System.out.println("" + tok.token + " " + tok.sequence);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
<!-- Sample input file with incomplete recipe -->
<recipe name="bread" prep_time="5 mins" cook_time="3 hours">
   <title>Basic bread</title>
   <ingredient amount="3" unit="cups">Flour</ingredient>
   <instructions>
     <step>Mix all ingredients together.</step>
   </instructions>
</recipe>
```

However, the outputted token list recognizes `<` and `/` (including whatever characters come after it) as separate tokens, meaning it can never seem to recognize the tokens `</` and `/>`. Same issue with the comments. Is this a problem with my regex? Why isn't it recognizing the patterns `</` and `/>`?

Hope my question is clear. Happy to provide more details/examples if necessary.

Comment: Are they added to the list in the order declared?

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML/XML, I recommend using an existing library instead.

Comment: You might want to mention where `TokenInfo` and `Pattern` come from.  (Assuming oAuth & java.util, but ... could be wrong)

Comment: @RamenChef I've tried changing the order but that didn't seem to change anything. Also, as this is a school project, I can't use external libraries. I've added my TokenInfo class to the OP.

Comment: @FieryPhoenix This really isn't even close to an [mcve].  Please add the code where you actually match your input against your list of tokens.  Also, add some sample input

Comment: @Tibrogargan Added the function that does the tokenizing as well as my test method. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Why do all your patterns start at the beginning of the line?  (`^`)

Comment: Ok, so you neeeeeed to pay attention to @4castle, also, please read [this](/a/1732454/2487517)

Comment: @Tibrogargan It wouldn't display the input in the order of appearance otherwise. I've read the list you provided. Does that mean my professor gave us an unsolvable assignment? That seems highly unlikely...

Comment: Did he explicitly say to use regular expressions?  (If so, he's a ....).  You should be using an XML/HTML Parser to parse HTML (there's an XML parser in the core libraries ...not the most awesome API though, sorry).  Also ... while you might be able to get away with using Regexp for this, I don't think `^` means what you think it means

Comment: no point in copying the string passed to `tokenize`.  As soon as you change str (by making it refer to the return value of `Matcher.replaceFirst` for example), it would no longer refer to the argument passed to tokenize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problems:

1. Your initial regex `^(<)` will match against the entire input. This regex means that the text has to start with `<` and the entire input string is just that. So you will have to fix it.
2. If the entire tag (without the text content - like *Basic Bread*, *Mix all ingredients together*) is considered a token. So the corresponding Regex should be a single regex.

## Solution

Try changing the Regex to the following:

1. For a single tag - `<[^>]*>`
2. For a single closing tag - `</[^>]*>`;
3. For comments - <!--.*--> (This is already correct)

## Sample Program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    private static ArrayList<TokenInfo> tokenInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> tokensList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void add(String regex, int token) {
        tokenInfoList.add(new TokenInfo(Pattern.compile(regex), token));
    }

    static {
        String LTHAN = "<[^>]*>";
        String LTHAN_SLASH = "</[^>]*>";
        String COMMENT = "<!--.*-->";
        add(LTHAN, 1);
        add(LTHAN_SLASH, 3);
        add(COMMENT, 5);
    }

    private static class TokenInfo {
        public final Pattern regex;
        public final int token;

        public TokenInfo(Pattern regex, int token) {
            super();
            this.regex = regex;
            this.token = token;
        }
    }

    public static void tokenize(String str) {
        String s = new String(str);
        while (!s.equals("")) {
            boolean match = false;
            for (TokenInfo info : tokenInfoList) {
                Matcher m = info.regex.matcher(s);
                if (m.find()) {
                    match = true;
                    String tok = m.group().trim();
                    tokensList.add(tok);
                    s = m.replaceFirst("");
                    break;
                }
            }
            // The following is under the assumption that the Text nodes within the document are not considered tokens and replaced
            if (!match) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br;
            String curLine;
            String EOF = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                File dir = new File("recipe.xml");
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir));

                while ((curLine = br.readLine()) != EOF) {
                    sb.append(curLine);
                    // System.out.println(curLine);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            tokenize(sb.toString());

            for (String eachToken : tokensList) {
               System.out.println(eachToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

## References

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great resource for learning regular expressions.

Comment: My friend, I thank you for this. Rather than questioning and judging my work, you actually lent me a hand. I appreciate it profusely.